# How to keep my car well maintained?

Tags: maintenance, fluid

I am a new driver and a new car owner. When I bought my car, I came to know I needed to change the engine oil to maintain the car. My car also gives an indicator to maintain oil. I can feel it when air gets low in the tire and such things. But I don't know which fluids should be replaced regularly to keep my car smooth and unrusted. Can anyone suggest which car fluids I should replace regularly?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

Your owners manual should have a service schedule for your particular car.  Here's one from a VW Beetle manual as an example (click for a larger view).

[image: VW Service Schedule]